# ios 8 - scroll does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, ios8

I am using `UIScrollView` . At run time I am adding `UIButton` into `scrollview`. In iOS 7 it work perfectly but in iOS 8 I am getting problem on scrolling (it is very hard to scroll )..

Here is my code . Please suggest me What am I doing wrong or in iOS 8 is there any  new property? .

```
-(void)renderAllCatealogue:(NSArray *)catalogueArr
{
  [[scollViewCatlog subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
  int x=0;
  for (NSDictionary *dict in catalogueArr)
   {
    UIView *view =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 8, 1, 16)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [scollViewCatlog addSubview: view];

    //calculate width
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:BOLD_FONT size:15];
    CGFloat width=[[CommonUISetting sharedInstance]widthOfString:[dict valueForKey:@"catalogTitle"] withFont:font];

    UIButton * btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x+10, 1, width, 30)];
    [btn setTitle:[dict valueForKey:@"catalogTitle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btn setTag:[[dict valueForKey:@"catalogId"] integerValue]];
    [btn.titleLabel setFont:font];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(catlogBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:BOLD_FONT size:15]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [scollViewCatlog addSubview:btn];
     x=x+width +15;

}
[scollViewCatlog setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x, 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got solution .

I create a subclass of `UIScrollview` and add  this method in it.

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view 
{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is a true lifesaver! I had the same scrolling issue and this was the only working solution.

Comment: Yep! Did it for me with same issue - thank you very much!
Adding this: Reminding that if you connect a a scroll view (or anything for that matter) to an outlet via the IB, don't forget to go (in the IB) to Identity Inspector tab on the right pane, and change the custom class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `UICollectionView` in order to generate something you want. `UICollectionView` allows to create vertical as well as horizontal infinite scroll panel. It is similar as the `UITableView`, you just have to setup some DataSource Methods and Delegate Methods.

look here for sample of [UICollectionView](http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/04/26/creating_scrolling_filmstrip_within_uitableview/)